# How to properly use asp.net server tags?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to search the net for any javascript that uses inline server variables like this:

```
<% {%> <%} %
```

Is this a recommended or standard usage in asp.net webforms?

I am currently having to mix server and javascript code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    jsMyStuff.SiteMaster.ServerData.Add('EmailAddress', '<%=EmailAddress%>');
    jsMyStuff.SiteMaster.ServerData.Add('ReturnURL', '<%=ReturnURL%>');

    $('footer div.std-grey-btn').click(function()
    {
        <%
        if (this.KeepUpToDate.Text.Length > 0)
        {%>
            $(location).attr('href', 'https://localhost/Websites/MySite/Email_Club_Sign_Up?ReturnUrl=' +
                               jsMyStuff.SiteMaster.ServerData['ReturnURL'].Value + "&hd" +
                               jsMyStuff.SiteMaster.ServerData['EmailAddress'].Value);
        <%}
        else
        %>
            return false;
    })
});
```

This builds ok.
Has anyone else used this convoluted syntax? Is it more closely related to mvc razor syntax ?  Is it wise or recommended ?

this.KeepUpToDate.Text.Length is server code in c#.net.

Comment: I'm not trying to use Razor - I'm using asp.net webforms.

Due to architectural requirements I am required to use the inline server tag syntax within <script></script> tags of an .aspx (acually a master) page.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it, other than the fact that it's difficult to read. When you're doing inline stuff like that in WebForms, you don't have much of a choice.

If you're going for clarity, you may want to just reorganize a bit, maybe try to get all of your server stuff away from the bulk of your javascript, like:

```
var keepUpToDate = "<%: this.KeepUpToDate.Text %>";

if (keepUpToDate) {
    $(location).attr('href', 'blah');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

There will be a little bit more that renders to the page, but it will be much clearer to read both in the aspx source, and in the rendered HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I actually confused myself in the asking of the question as I thought there was such a thing as: '<% {%> <%} %' as server tag syntax in and of itself, (which there isn't).